# uso correcto de having by

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola queria saber si estoy haciendo lo correcto con las siguientes tablas

```
NUMOBJ | IDIOMA 
1      | E
1      | I
2      | E
2      | I
3      | E
3      | I
```

tabla1: cada objeto con todos los idiomas posibles (2)

```
NUMOBJ | IDIOMA 
1      | E
1      | I
2      | I
3      | E
```

tabla2: cada objeto con los idiomas q en realidad tiene

```
create view V as

select numobj, 
case 
when count(*) < 2 then 0
else 1
end as Tag
from Tabla1 as T1
left join Tabla2 as T2
on T1.numobj = T2.numobj
where T1.idioma = T2.idioma
GROUP  BY T1.numobj, T2.numobj
```

Esta consulta anyade una columna `Tag` que sera 1 si el objeto de la tabla 2 posee los 2 `idiomas` y sera 0 si solo posee uno, asi:

```
NUMOBJ | TAG
1      | 1
2      | 0
3      | 0
```

Ahora lo que quiero hacer es tener otra columa que me diga que idioma le falta al objeto en caso de ser 0, asi:

```
NUMOBJ | TAG | FALTA(N)
1      | 1   | 
2      | 0   | E
3      | 0   | I
```

Alguien sabe si se puede hacer esto? he probado alguna cosa pero con el `group by` no me deja utilizar las columnas que no estan agrupadas (`IDIOMAS`).
Agradezco cualquier ayuda o pista, muchas gracias.

R.

Comment: has intentando de la misma forma que trae el 1 o el 0 traer el valor con el case ?

Comment: si pero no me deja utilizar la columna idioma pq no está contenida en el group by

Comment: ¿Solo dos idiomas vas a tener como máximo?

Comment: no, de hecho hay otra tabla llamada idiomas en las que podria haber mas de 2, lo he puesto asi para simplificar un poco pq me parece una consulta bastante compleja para mi nivel.

Comment: he formulado mejor la pregunta en https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/188373/uso-correcto-de-group-by

Answer (score 0):

Hola espero que te sirva ...  saludos ....

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mysql

```
select numobj, tag, faltan from (select t1.*,t2.idioma, if(t1.tag=1,'',if(t2.idioma='E','I','E')) as faltan from (select T1.numobj, case 
when count(*) < 2 then 0
else 1
end as Tag
from Tabla1 T1 left join Tabla2 T2 on T1.numobj = T2.numobj
where T1.idioma = T2.idioma
GROUP  BY T1.numobj, T2.numobj ) as t1  left join Tabla2 t2 on t1.numobj = t2.numobj GROUP  BY t1.numobj) as tabla
```

Comment: muchas gracias, una idea me da para seguir trabajando, pero realmente podrian haber mas idiomas, tengo otra tabla que contiene los idiomas en los que debe estar cada objeto, por ejemplo tabla idiomas contiene E,I,D,F,   por lo que en la consulta no puedo especificar el idioma. muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: he formulado mejor la pregunta en https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/188373/uso-correcto-de-group-by

Comment: tu respuesta me da el error 'Column 'numobj' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause', estoy utilizando sql server