# ¿Cómo agrupar y concatenar las filas de cada grupo en una determinada columna?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ya había formulado esto resumido en un post anterior, pero he decidido hacer la pregunta complete porque no me ha ayudado mucho:

Tengo las siguientes tablas:

Tabla 1 con los objetos y las versiones que tiene:

```
+-------------+----------------+
| Num_objeto  | Version_objeto |
+-------------+----------------+
|           1 | A              |
|           1 | B              |
|           2 | A              |
|           2 | B              |
|           2 | D              |
|           3 | A              |
|           4 | M              |
+-------------+----------------+
```

Tabla 2 con cada (objeto, versión) con los idiomas disponibles:

```
+------------+----------------+--------+
| Num_objeto | Version_objeto | Idioma |
+------------+----------------+--------+
|          1 | A              | I      |
|          1 | B              | I      |
|          1 | B              | E      |
|          2 | A              | E      |
|          2 | B              | I      |
|          2 | B              | E      |
|          2 | B              | A      |
|          2 | D              | E      |
|          3 | A              | E      |
|          4 | M              | I      |
|          4 | M              | A      |
+------------+----------------+--------+
```

Y otra Tabla 3 con los idiomas disponibles, en este caso 3 por simplicidad pero podrían ser más

```
+--------+----------+
| Idioma |  Texto   |
+--------+----------+
| I      | Ingles   |
| E      | Espanyol |
| A      | Aleman   |
+--------+----------+
```

Y por fin la table/vista con el resultado que quiero, para cada (objeto, versión) una Etiqueta que me diga si están en todos los idiomas, y en caso de no estarlo, otro campo. Falta que me diga que idiomas faltan, para que quedara así:

```
+------------+----------------+----------+--------+
| Num_Objeto | Version_Objeto | Etiqueta | Faltan |
+------------+----------------+----------+--------+
|          1 | A              |        0 | A,E    |
|          1 | B              |        0 | A      |
|          2 | A              |        0 | A,I    |
|          2 | B              |        1 |        |
|          2 | D              |        0 | A,I    |
|          3 | A              |        0 | A,I    |
|          4 | M              |        0 | E      |
+------------+----------------+----------+--------+
```

De momento gracias a la ayuda de la respuesta de @Carmen  tengo el siguiente query, pero no me funciona la concatenacion, estoy usando bien el stuff? por cierto no me deja usar el string_agg

```
SELECT a.num_objeto,a.version_objeto,
case
    when COUNT(*)< (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabla3 b) then 0
    else 1
    end as completo,
case <br>
    when COUNT(*)< (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabla3 b) then
    ( stuff((SELECT d.Idioma
      FROM tabla3 d
      WHERE d.Idioma NOT IN (
        SELECT c.Idioma FROM tabla2 c
        WHERE c.num_objeto=a.num_objeto AND c.version_objeto=a.version_objeto
      )),1,1,''))
     else ''
     end AS LANG
FROM tabla2 a
GROUP BY a.num_objeto,a.version_objeto;
```

Comment: he editado la respuesta para que te funcione en sql-server. Te dejo la query y un ejemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Antes que nada crearemos las tablas de ejemplos que has planteado en tu pregunta:

```
DECLARE @Tabla1 TABLE (
    Num_objeto  INT,
    Version_objeto  CHAR
)

INSERT INTO @Tabla1 (Num_objeto, Version_objeto)
    VALUES  (1, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (2, 'A'), (2, 'B'), 
        (2, 'D'), (3, 'A'), (4, 'M')

DECLARE @Tabla2 TABLE (
    Num_objeto  INT,
    Version_objeto  CHAR,
    Idioma      CHAR
)

INSERT INTO @Tabla2 (Num_objeto, Version_objeto, Idioma)
    VALUES  (1, 'A', 'I'), (1, 'B', 'I'), (1, 'B', 'E'), (2, 'A', 'E'), (2, 'B', 'I'), 
        (2, 'B', 'E'), (2, 'B', 'A'), (2, 'D', 'E'), (3, 'A', 'E'), (4, 'M', 'I'),
        (4, 'M', 'A')

DECLARE @Tabla3 TABLE (
    Idioma  CHAR,
    Texto   VARCHAR(255)
)
INSERT INTO @Tabla3 (Idioma, Texto)
    VALUES ('I', 'Ingles'), ('E', 'Espanyol'), ('A', 'Aleman')
```

Lo principal, es saber que idiomas faltan para cada valor de `Num_objeto` y `Version_objeto`:

```
SELECT  T2.Num_objeto,
    T2.Version_objeto,
    T1.Idioma
    FROM @Tabla3 T1
    CROSS JOIN @Tabla1 T2
    LEFT JOIN @Tabla2 T3
        ON T3.Idioma = T1.Idioma
        AND T3.Num_objeto = T2.Num_objeto
        AND T3.Version_objeto = T2.Version_objeto
    WHERE   T3.Idioma IS NULL
    ORDER BY T2.Num_objeto, 
        T2.Version_objeto,
        T1.Idioma
```

por cada idioma, hacemos un producto cartesiano(`CROSS JOIN`) con cada uno de los objetos y verificamos aquellos a los que le falte un idioma. Con esto obtenemos cada `Num_objeto` y `Version_objeto` y el `Idioma` que le estaría faltando. A partir de aquí hay dos problemas a resolver:

- Concatenar los valores de los idiomas por cada `Num_objeto` y `Version_objeto`
- Agregar aquel objeto que tenga todos los idiomas

El primer punto lo haremos aplicando un [`FOR XML PATH`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) (válido a partir de SQL 2008) para concatenar los valores de los idiomas por cada objeto y lo segundo, simplemente traeremos aquellos objetos que no estén contenidos en el conjunto de los que le falte algún idioma. Usaremos también una ["common table expresion"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), solo para hacer más compacta la escritura, si te funciona el `FOR XML PATH` debería funcionar también el `WITH common_table_expression`. Veamos:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT  T2.Num_objeto,
    T2.Version_objeto,
    T1.Idioma
    FROM @Tabla3 T1
    CROSS JOIN @Tabla1 T2
    LEFT JOIN @Tabla2 T3
        ON T3.Idioma = T1.Idioma
        AND T3.Num_objeto = T2.Num_objeto
        AND T3.Version_objeto = T2.Version_objeto
    WHERE   T3.Idioma IS NULL
)

SELECT  T1.Num_objeto, 
    T1.Version_objeto,
    0 AS 'Etiqueta',
    STUFF(T2.Idiomas, 1, 1, '') AS 'Idiomas'
    FROM  CTE T1
        CROSS APPLY
        (
           SELECT ',' + T3.Idioma
           FROM   CTE T3
           WHERE  T3.Num_objeto = T1.Num_objeto
        AND T3.Version_objeto = T1.Version_objeto
           FOR XML PATH ('')
        ) T2 (Idiomas)
    GROUP BY T1.Num_objeto, 
        T1.Version_objeto,
        STUFF(T2.Idiomas, 1, 1, '')
UNION

SELECT  T1.Num_objeto, 
    T1.Version_objeto,
    1 AS 'Etiqueta',
    NULL
    FROM @Tabla1 T1
    LEFT JOIN CTE T2
        ON T1.Num_objeto = T2.Num_objeto
        AND T1.Version_objeto = T2.Version_objeto
    WHERE T2.Num_objeto IS NULL
    ORDER BY [Num_objeto], [Version_objeto]
```

finalmente el resultado:

```
╔════════════╦════════════════╦══════════╦═════════╗
║ Num_objeto ║ Version_objeto ║ Etiqueta ║ Idiomas ║
╠════════════╬════════════════╬══════════╬═════════╣
║ 1,00       ║ A              ║ 0,00     ║ E,A     ║
╠════════════╬════════════════╬══════════╬═════════╣
║ 1,00       ║ B              ║ 0,00     ║ A       ║
╠════════════╬════════════════╬══════════╬═════════╣
║ 2,00       ║ A              ║ 0,00     ║ I,A     ║
╠════════════╬════════════════╬══════════╬═════════╣
║ 2,00       ║ B              ║ 1,00     ║         ║
╠════════════╬════════════════╬══════════╬═════════╣
║ 2,00       ║ D              ║ 0,00     ║ I,A     ║
╠════════════╬════════════════╬══════════╬═════════╣
║ 3,00       ║ A              ║ 0,00     ║ I,A     ║
╠════════════╬════════════════╬══════════╬═════════╣
║ 4,00       ║ M              ║ 0,00     ║ E       ║
╚════════════╩════════════════╩══════════╩═════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola espero que esta sea tu solución a pesar que la primera linea de tu reporte final este mal  E,I debe ser E,A.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

MYSQL

```
select
    table1.num_objeto,
    table1.version_objeto,
        case when count(*) < (
        select count(*)
        from table3
    ) then 0 else 1 end as Etiqueta,
    CONCAT(
    if(sum(if(table3.idioma='E',1,0))=1,'','E'),
    if(sum(if(table3.idioma='A',1,0))=1,'','A'),
    if(sum(if(table3.idioma='I',1,0))=1,'','I')
    ) as faltan
from
    table1
    cross join table3
    left join table2 on table1.num_objeto = table2.num_objeto
    and table1.version_objeto = table2.version_objeto
where
    table3.idioma = table2.idioma
GROUP BY
    table1.num_objeto,
    table2.num_objeto,
    table2.version_objeto
```

Saludos y la prox. siempre da tu ejemplo real así se te puede ayudar mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Te añado una respuesta que te permite sacar los datos deseados en función de la tabla de idiomas, independientemente del número de registros que tengas en esta tabla, ya que comprueba cuántos idiomas existen en tu tabla. Esto resulta más cómodo de manejar, pero si las tablas que manejas son muy grandes puede llegar a ser una consulta lenta.

Siendo tu tabla 2 'docs' y tu tabla 3 'langs':

```
SELECT a.`Num_objeto`,a.`Version_objeto`, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL,
IF (COUNT(*)< (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `langs` b), '0', '1') AS COMPLETO,
IF (COUNT(*)< (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `langs` b), 
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(d.`Idioma`)
      FROM `langs` d
      WHERE d.`Idioma` NOT IN ( 
        SELECT c.`Idioma` FROM `docs` c 
        WHERE c.`Num_objeto`=a.`Num_objeto` AND c.`Version_objeto`=a.`Version_objeto`
      ))
    , '') AS LANG
FROM `docs` a
GROUP BY a.`Num_objeto`,a.`Version_objeto`;
```

Puedes ver un ejemplo funcionando [aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a7508/24). Espero que te sirva.

Sólo como observación, tu tabla 1 está contenida al completo en la tabla 2, sino contienen más campos es un diseño poco eficaz.

**Editado:** esta sería la query para `sql` con `STRING_AGG` en lugar de `GROUP_CONCAT`, que es de `mysql`.

```
SELECT a.num_objeto,a.version_objeto,
case
when (COUNT(*)< (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM langs b)) then 0
else 1
end as completo,

case
when COUNT(*)< (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM langs b) then
( SELECT STRING_AGG(d.Idioma,',')
  FROM langs d
  WHERE d.Idioma NOT IN (
  SELECT c.Idioma FROM docs c
  WHERE c.num_objeto=a.num_objeto AND c.version_objeto=a.version_objeto
))
else ''
end AS LANG

FROM docs a
GROUP BY a.num_objeto,a.version_objeto;
```

Puedes ver un ejemplo funcionando [aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ad678/19).

Comment: muchas gracias, quizas deberia haber especificado que es para sql server, los ifs ya los he editado, pero cual seria el equivalente a group_concat?

Comment: Pues buscando parece que podría hacerse con STUFF o STRING_AGG, esta última es más nueva y sencilla [https://database.guide/the-sql-server-equivalent-to-group_concat/]

Comment: he probado el stuff pero no me funciona, he editado el post si puedes echarle un vistazo a ver si ves el error. gracias

Answer (score 0):

En este caso primero genero una subquery (sqP) con todas las posibilidades de objetos, versiones e idiomas (CROSS JOIN tabla1 y tabla3). Luego hago un LEFT JOIN entre dicha subquery y la tabla2 vinculando por las tres columnas. Agrupo por Num_objeto y Version_objeto de la subquery. Las columnas Etiqueta y Faltan las defino en función de las columnas Idioma de la subquery y la tabla2. Por ejemplo en la columna Faltan concateno sqP.Idioma si t2.Idioma es nulo (concateno todos los idiomas faltantes).

```
SELECT sqP.Num_objeto, 
       sqP.Version_objeto,
       CASE WHEN count(sqP.Idioma) = count(t2.Idioma) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Etiqueta,
       STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN t2.Idioma IS NULL THEN sqP.Idioma END, ',') AS Faltan
      
FROM (SELECT ov.Num_objeto, ov.Version_objeto, i.Idioma
      FROM tabla1 ov
      CROSS JOIN tabla3 i) AS sqP
      
LEFT JOIN tabla2 t2 ON sqP.Num_objeto = t2.Num_objeto 
                       AND sqP.Version_objeto = t2.Version_objeto
                       AND sqP.Idioma = t2.Idioma 

GROUP BY sqP.Num_objeto, sqP.Version_objeto
ORDER BY sqP.Num_objeto, sqP.Version_objeto;
```

Resultado (según datos de ejemplo de la pregunta):

| Num_objeto | Version_objeto | Etiqueta | Faltan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 0 | A,E |
| 1 | B | 0 | A |
| 2 | A | 0 | A,I |
| 2 | B | 1 |  |
| 2 | D | 0 | A,I |
| 3 | A | 0 | A,I |
| 4 | M | 0 | E |